# Placing array of objects as a table inside a cell : React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am trying to implement a table where in some of the data that I receive from backend is a nested array of objects and I want to display it in a cell of that column like a table with key value pair

```
 const data = [
      {
        firstName: "Jack",
        status: "Submitted",
        nested: [
          {
            name: "test1",
            value: "NA"
          },
          {
            name: "test2",
            value: "NA"
          }
        ],
        age: "14"
      }
    ];
```

I am able to place the rest of the fields(except nested) that I receive from the API . Can someone help how to place this array of objects inside of a cell as table like  key value pairs

I am using react table v6 for this application

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-47192

Want the output something like with `show more` if items are more than 2 and then followed by the toggle for `show less`

```
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
| firstname | status    | age | nested          |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
| Jack      | Submitted | 14  | name  value     |
|           |           |     | -----------     |
|           |           |     | test1  NA       |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     | test2  NA       |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     |  Show More/Less |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
| Simon     | Pending   | 15  | name  value     |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     | -----------     |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     | test3  NA       |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     | test4  Go       |
|           |           |     |                 |
|           |           |     | Show More/Less  |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      columns: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getData = () => {
    const data = [
      {
        firstName: "Jack",
        status: "Submitted",
        nested: [
          {
            name: "test1",
            value: "NA"
          },
          {
            name: "test2",
            value: "NA"
          }
        ],
        age: "14"
      },
      {
        firstName: "Simon",
        status: "Pending",
        nested: [
          {
            name: "test3",
            value: "NA"
          },
          {
            name: "test4",
            value: "Go"
          }
        ],
        age: "15"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  getColumns = () => {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      },
      {
        Header: "Nested",
        id: "nested",
        accessor: data => {
          let output = [];
          data.nested.map(item => {
            return output.push(item.value);
          });
          return output.join(", ");
        }
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Edit: I have updated the code sandbox link based on the comment

> LastEdit: If you want you can change the look like by adding `SubComponent`
>   props to the `ReactTable`
>
> I have created a sample sandbox where I added `SubComponent`

[New Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-y89jd?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: check the new sandbox link if it suits your requirement

Comment: have added the edit in the question, on how the table should look. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know if this functionality is available in ReactTable but it's very much achievable basic onClick callback and slicing the array

Comment: Thanks. Only thing is how to bring the table headers and stuff. Just getting view in place. Your sandbox missed table headers

Comment: Just hard code the values then If it’s not a dynamic value

Comment: It is dynamic in my case